# App Groups just won't work between my Message Filter Extension and the host app

Tags: ios

I've had this running in the past for my other app (between a Today extension and the host app), however, for a brand new app created with Xcode 9.1 I see strange errors:

```
2017-12-25 17:16:42.077247+0530 Controller[851:11684] [User Defaults] Couldn't read values in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x10470c970> (Domain: group.com.judepereira, User: kCFPreferencesAnyUser, ByHost: Yes, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: Yes): Using kCFPreferencesAnyUser with a container is only allowed for System Containers, detaching from cfprefsd
2017-12-25 17:16:42.079711+0530 Controller[851:11707] [User Defaults] Couldn't write value for key idc in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x10470c620> (Domain: group.com.judepereira, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: No): setting preferences outside an application's container requires user-preference-write or file-write-data sandbox access, switching to read-only
2017-12-25 17:16:42.081354+0530 Controller[851:11707] [User Defaults] Couldn't write value for key rules in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x10470c620> (Domain: group.com.judepereira, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: No): Operation not allowed, switching to read-only
```

I've followed the guides specified [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html) and [here](http://www.atomicbird.com/blog/sharing-with-app-extensions). Moreover, what's even more weird is that it works perfectly within the host app. I see these random errors only when my Message Filter Extension tries to update the user defaults for this app group.

Here's how I'm updating it:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]
                            initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.judepereira"];

NSLog(@"idc=%@", [defaults objectForKey:@"idc"]);
[defaults setObject:@"judepereira" forKey:@"idc"];
```

Further, I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39876042/nsuserdefaults-errors-in-logs) and [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/51348) about how a reboot of the device solves it, and also that these error messages are just some spurious warnings.

Comment: I tried the opposite, getting a value from the host app
always returns nil
did you overcome it? 
Maybe it's not supported in this specific extension

Answer (score 1):

After further investigation it's not allowed in this particular extension 
An answer from apple.

> For privacy reasons, the system handles all communication with your
>   associated server; your Message Filter app extension can't access the
>   network directly.
>
> Also for privacy reasons, your app extension can't write data to
>   containers shared with the containing app.
>
> You should not be writing data to a shared container for this
>   particular type of Application Extension. Generally, you can use App
>   Groups with NSUserDefaults to communicate information between your App
>   and its Extensions.

Comment: Yes, I got the same reply from Apple.

Comment: So conclusion is that, we cannot send data from Message Extension to main app?