# Log error when accessing the apple menu in a Sandboxed macOS App

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I'm running the just-released macOS 10.12.2, Xcode 8.2, Swift 3.

I have a strange error that comes up in all my sandboxed macOS apps.  When I run the apps from Xcode and click on the Apple Menu (top left), the following error logs to the console in Xcode,

> 2016-12-13 19:30:55.867046 Project-X[3430:411160] [User Defaults]
>   Failed  to read values in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x6100000e3f00> (Domain: 
>   com.apple.PowerManagement, User: kCFPreferencesAnyUser, ByHost: Yes, 
>   Container: (null)): accessing preferences outside an application's
>   container  requires user-preference-read or file-read-data sandbox
>   access, detaching from  cfprefsd

If I create a build, save it to my Mac as a local app and run it from there, I see the same error as above listed in the macOS console, in addition to this error listed as a FAULT under the `cfprefsd` process:

> rejecting read of { com.apple.PowerManagement, kCFPreferencesAnyUser,
>   kCFPreferencesCurrentHost, no container, managed: 0 } from process
>   3384 because accessing preferences outside an application's container
>   requires user-preference-read or file-read-data sandbox access

..and this under the `kernel` process:

```
SandboxViolation: Project-X(3384) deny(1) file-read-data
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.PowerManagement.plist
```

If I create a build ***without*** sandboxing, the error doesn't show up anywhere.

My entitlement settings are just these two:

- App Sandbox
- com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write

I had the same issue in 10.12.1 and thought it might be resolved in 10.12.2, but it persists.  It's strangely specific, because it only presents if I click on the Apple Menu when the app is running.

Thanks very much for any insights!!

Comment: If a question concerns Cocoa sandbox, you will probably have better luck getting an answer at Apple'd developer forums.

Comment: Great idea!  Thanks.  I'll post it there too.

Comment: I met the same problem, have you solved it?

Comment: Not yet, but thanks very much for your reply -- it's nice to know that I'm not the only one.  I posted this on the Apple Developer Forums, but my post is still in the "pending" queue waiting for a moderator to approve it.  If I find out anything else, I'll update the information here.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275395/failed-to-read-values-in-cfprefsplistsource-ios-10 but the news isn't good.

Comment: Thanks. I did see that, but thought it might be unique to iOS.  Looks like it affects macOS as well.

Comment: I have seen this a few times now.. A computer reboot solves it for me for a while.

Comment: Thanks for the update!  Anyone testing the 10.12.4 beta know if this has been fixed?

Comment: From what I can see, the problem persists in 10.12.4 & Xcode 8.3 :-(

Answer (score 1):

If the error persists, you may use a temporary exeption entitlement key to access the plist in question.

```
<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-only</key>
<array>
        <string>/Library/Preferences/com.apple.PowerManagement.plist</string>
</array>
```