# Failed to read values in CFPrefsPlistSource, when I access core data with app group

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I tried to access in today extension with app group. But, I got a some error.

error message is here

```
[User Defaults] Failed to read values in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x1700f1280> (Domain: group.x.p.t.o, User: kCFPreferencesAnyUser, ByHost: Yes, Container: (null)): Using kCFPreferencesAnyUser with a container is only allowed for System Containers, detaching from cfprefsd
```

I'm using Xcode 8.3, iOS10.

And here is my container

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {


    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "x")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { [weak self](storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error {
                NSLog("CoreData error \(error)")
                self?.errorHandler(error)
            }
        })
        return container
}()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to read values in CFPrefsPlistSource iOS 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275395/failed-to-read-values-in-cfprefsplistsource-ios-10)

Comment: @AnthonyKong This doesn't work for me ;(

Comment: OK. I retracted my close vote.

Comment: Lucy, how did you solve this?

Comment: @SAHM nope.. :(