# Share data between main app and today widget macOS

Tags: swift, xcode, macos-sierra, today-extension

I'm trying to share data between my main macOS app and the extension I created.
I saw I have to use the "App Groups" and share the data with "UserDefault(suiteName: "name")"

The problem : After turned on App Groups on the main app and added a name, I then turn on App Groups on extension and the list is empty, I don't see the group I'v just created ?

Any idea ?

btw: the team profil is the same on both app and extension. I'v tried to delete temporary file, clean project, restored Xcode and computer.

[image]

**EDIT 1 : On iOS project the app groups are detected...**.
**EDIT 2 : I tried with Xcode 9 but same problem**.
**EDIT 3 : On Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles apple website, you don't have the category "App Groups" for macOS, is it deprecated ??**
**EDIT 4 : If I add both add groups names manually, then I got an error in output :**. 
[User Defaults] Failed to read values in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x6000000e4200> (Domain: 726328455Z.test, User: kCFPreferencesAnyUser, ByHost: Yes, Container: (null)): Using kCFPreferencesAnyUser with a container is only allowed for System Containers, detaching from cfprefsd.

**Edit 5 :  Looks like it work, the data is successfully saved with this code**

```
UserDefaults(suiteName: "7263xxx55Z.test")!.set(selectedRow, forKey: "selectedRow")
UserDefaults(suiteName: "7263xxx55Z.test")!.synchronize()
```

And fetch with this code, I got the previous error but I just ignore it

```
let selectedRow = UserDefaults(suiteName: "726xxx55Z.test")!.integer(forKey: "selectedRow")
```

Comment: Did you try to click on the plus sign and add the group name?

Comment: yes I did, with same app name, start by team number, by group. etc and nothing worked

Comment: do you have admin rights of developer account?

Comment: yes I have only 1 account and I'm the developer

Comment: solution fixed ?

Comment: yes it is. . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To share data between app/app extension in macOS project :**

**1/** In your Main project target, select Capabilities and enable "App Groups".

**2/** Click on "+" and add a new app group name, it must start with your team ID (e.g. 643J438K.name.app)

**3/** Repeat 1/ and 2/ for your extension app target, be sure to add the same name

**4/** To save and fetch data use :

```
// Store data
UserDefaults(suiteName: "643J438K.name.app")!.set(yourVariable, forKey: "yourKey")
UserDefaults(suiteName: "643J438K.name.app")!.synchronize()

// Fetch data (integer type here)
UserDefaults(suiteName: "643J438K.name.app")!.integer(forKey: "yourKey")
```

**5/** You can check that your data is correctly saved by opening this file :

```
/Users/UserName/Library/Group Containers/643J438K.name.app/Preferences/643J438K.name.app.plist
```

Comment: I tried that, but I get this error in the console: `Unsatisfied entitlements: com.apple.security.application-groups`