# kCFPreferencesAnyUser with a container is only allowed for System Containers

Tags: ios

I have an app that shares preferences with a Today extension, following the approach described in many places (like [this](http://blog.intrepid.io/ios-app-extensions)), i.e., creating and registering an App Group, then loading preferences:

```
if let ud = UserDefaults(suitName: "group.myshop.MyDefaultsSuite") {
  let myPref = ud.string(forKey: "myUserName")
  ...
}
```

This worked fine through about April, 2016, and I didn't touch the app for a long time. Then I downloaded the latest Xcode (v8.3.3) and updated my code for Swift 3 as reflected above.

However, now on the `ud.string()` line I get a console warning `Using kCFPreferencesAnyUser with a container is only allowed for System Containers, detaching from cfprefsd`. And my preferences fail to load. I've seen [other issues posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275395/failed-to-read-values-in-cfprefsplistsource-ios-10#) that look very similar, but no solutions. I'd rather not rename my preferences bundle or pre-pend my group ID as that would effectively block access to previously saved settings.

Has anyone else found a solution?

Comment: I have not seen this error in iOS, but in running with Catalyst on macOS I see it and my preferences cannot be read/written

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Not really. I ended up taking out the Today extension as it turned out not to be terribly useful for my app. I haven't looked at the issue in quite a while so I'm not sure if there's a better approach these days - sorry.

Comment: Found this issue right now on ios 14.4