# <Error>: Couldn't read values in CFPrefsPlistSource

Tags: ios

I'm facing some problems with iOS 11. We use App Groups to share some information between some of our apps, but some clients after updated their iPhone to iOS 11+ the apps stoped accessing the information in the App Groups. It always worked.

I'm getting following error:

> Couldn't read values in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x1c010b5b0> (Domain: group.com.****, User: kCFPreferencesAnyUser, ByHost: Yes, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: Yes): Using kCFPreferencesAnyUser with a container is only allowed for System Containers, detaching from cfprefsd

Anyone has any idea of what can be causing this? Some clients after delete all apps and install again resolved the problem, but some said that it didn't resolved (I don't know if they really deleted all of our apps).

There is some way to recycle or clean the App Groups?

Comment: Hi I think this link has the accepted answer. It can help you.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275395/failed-to-read-values-in-cfprefsplistsource-ios-10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275395/failed-to-read-values-in-cfprefsplistsource-ios-10)

Comment: I'm already read this post. Unfortunately it didn't help me in my problema :(.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to read values in CFPrefsPlistSource iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275395/failed-to-read-values-in-cfprefsplistsource-ios-10)

Answer (score 1):

From watch OS 2 we are not able to access app groups so if you want to get any info from keychain e.g login info or some thing, you can use watch connectivity framework. When I tried to access some information from userdefault which worked fine in watchOS1 it shows me the same error after upgrading watchOS . For how work with watch connectivity please see this link. Here everything is explained.

https://kristina.io/watchos-2-how-to-communicate-between-devices-using-watch-connectivity/

Answer (score 1):

In my case error was caused by the fact, that I was trying to create plist file named "settings.plist" inside of the Shared Container the iOS provides us for access via AppGroup.

Seems like it prevents us to create files with names similar to os & core functionality.

*Changing the filename, for example "07087_settings" – removes the error, changing back to "settings" – throws error again.*