# User Defaults couldn't read values in CFPrefsPlistSource

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults, appgroups

I have a messaging app where I use an app extension to be able to look up contact information when I receive an APN containing a new message. I exchange the Addressbook contacts info which I have saved in my app through app groups with the help of NSUserDefaults.

Recently I keep getting the below error:

> [User Defaults] Couldn't read values in CFPrefsPlistSource (Domain:
> group.com.xxxx.xxxx, User: kCFPreferencesAnyUser, ByHost: Yes,
> Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: Yes): Using
> kCFPreferencesAnyUser with a container is only allowed for System
> Containers, detaching from cfprefsd

This sometimes returns empty NSUserDefaults throughout my app and makes the app behave as a first time use. I have looked at other link, especificly this one: [Failed to read values in CFPrefsPlistSource iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275395/failed-to-read-values-in-cfprefsplistsource-ios-10)

None of the suggested solutions solved my problem. Anyone knows how I should proceed with this?

Comment: is it solved?  can you gave the answer?

Comment: @lauwis unfortunately I have been unable to find a solution. Our product has this warning at all times however I reverted from using NSUserdefaults for important data and instead used PDKeychain... Not ideal but what can one do!

Answer (score -1):

I added this answer to a similar question: [Failed to read values in CFPrefsPlistSource iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275395/failed-to-read-values-in-cfprefsplistsource-ios-10/77923029#77923029)

There are other things to try there.

My issue ended up being I didn't realize your MacOS AppGroups and iOS AppGroups must live on separate targets.  MacOS needs the ID to have that `MYTEAMID` right at the beginning and iOS needs `group.`. Xcode 15 autocorrects the number leading appgroup ids to `group.` leading appgroup ids if iOS anything is on the target at all. You can't just `#if os(macOS)` in your code to pick which one you want, they must be *separate targets* with *separate entitlement files*.

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers to multiple questions. Instead, answer one question and then flag the other question(s) as a duplicate.

Comment: Makes sense. Apologies.