# Blank screen while building for ios using unity

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, unity-game-engine, onesignal

So I'm using **unity 2020.3.25f1** to build for the ios and I'm getting a blank screen on the Startup this is when I have implemented the onesignal notification Package got this error while building

```
Couldn't read values in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x2830fe500>
```

in unity in the code so after googling I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275395/failed-to-read-values-in-cfprefsplistsource-ios-10) to change the app group so this error was gone and a new error came like this in Xcode console

```
2022-02-15 16:55:30.312438+0530 ErrixsAdventure[1808:630903] UnityIAP UnityEarlyTransactionObserver: Created
2022-02-15 16:55:30.312751+0530 ErrixsAdventure[1808:630903] UnityIAP UnityEarlyTransactionObserver: Registered for lifecycle events
2022-02-15 16:55:30.361051+0530 ErrixsAdventure[1808:630903] FCM: Loading UIApplication FIRFCM category
2022-02-15 16:55:30.718566+0530 ErrixsAdventure[1808:630903] Loading UIApplication category for Firebase App
2022-02-15 16:55:30.898812+0530 ErrixsAdventure[1808:630903] Built from '2020.3/staging' branch, Version '2020.3.25f1 (9b9180224418)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp'
2022-02-15 16:55:30.899264+0530 ErrixsAdventure[1808:630903] MemoryManager: Using 'Default' Allocator.
2022-02-15 16:55:30.973658+0530 ErrixsAdventure[1808:630903] Setting up iOS 10 message delegate.
2022-02-15 16:55:30.980066+0530 ErrixsAdventure[1808:630903] [TraitCollection] Class CKBrowserSwitcherViewController overrides the -traitCollection getter, which is not supported. If you're trying to override traits, you must use the appropriate API.
2022-02-15 16:55:30.980271+0530 ErrixsAdventure[1808:630903] [TraitCollection] Class CKFunCameraViewController overrides the -traitCollection getter, which is not supported. If you're trying to override traits, you must use the appropriate API.
2022-02-15 16:55:30.980318+0530 ErrixsAdventure[1808:630903] [TraitCollection] Class CKExpandedAppViewController overrides the -traitCollection getter, which is not supported. If you're trying to override traits, you must use the appropriate API.
2022-02-15 16:55:31.167997+0530 ErrixsAdventure[1808:630903] [TraitCollection] Class PXImportHistorySectionHeaderView overrides the -traitCollection getter, which is not supported. If you're trying to override traits, you must use the appropriate API.
-> applicationDidFinishLaunching()
2022-02-15 16:55:31.397400+0530 ErrixsAdventure[1808:630903] UnityIAP UnityEarlyTransactionObserver: Added to the payment queue
-> applicationDidBecomeActive()
[Subsystems] Discovering subsystems at path /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/54620BBC-6D7D-4F49-87B3-AAE568F6B9B7/ErrixsAdventure.app/Data/UnitySubsystems
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1
Initializing Metal device caps: Apple A14 GPU
Initialize engine version: 2020.3.25f1 (9b9180224418)
UnloadTime: 0.411875 ms
2022-02-15 16:55:32.280501+0530 ErrixsAdventure[1808:630903] UnityIAP: Requesting 2 products
warning: could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data in the process. This may reduce the quality of type information available.
(lldb)
```

In the project, I have implemented some firebase packages, onesignal and Unity IAP